# Regexp в Java

Tags: регулярные-выражения, java

Здравствуйте, разработчики!

Мне нужно разбить на кусочки строку из IANA Ports, в общем случае она выглядит вот так:

`sim-control     3110/tcp   simulator control port`

Нужно извлечь "имя", "порт" и "протокол"

Использую следующую функцию, но почему-то протокол в m.group() не попадает

```
private LinuxService splitLSLine(String line) throws CfcException {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([-a-zAz]+)(?:\\s?|\\t?)+(\\d+)\\/(tcp|udp)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
    if(m.find()) {
        for(int i=0; i<m.groupCount(); i++) {
            System.out.println(m.group(i));
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Подскажите, почему? Или подскажите альтернативный метод с регулярными выражениями. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил я, было дело, попробовать посмотреть, а что кроется за пределами m.groupCount().
Получил, что элементов в массиве m.groupCount()+1.

Почему оно так, могу предположить, но не думал я, что такое может случиться.

Comment: Оказывается, документация это четко оговаривает
http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#groupCount%28%29.
Хотя для меня это тоже сюрприз.

Comment: Спасибо, большое за помощь. Не лез в документацию ибо на автомате весь count равен реальному размеру массива.

Comment: Это потому, что это никакой не массив. Вам не надо было лезть в документацию.. она всегда всплывает сама в любой приличной IDE.

Comment: Да, да, прошу прощения, что не смотрю, что пишет JavaDoc -> "Group zero denotes the entire pattern by convention. It is not included in this count."

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте скобки вокруг протокола:

```
([-a-zAz]+)(?:\\s?|\\t?)+(\\d+)\\/((tcp|udp))
```